# Develop a website that tracks phones using GPS

Tags: php, gps

We are currently halfway developing our thesis and there's a certain module we are having a hard time with. It's about a module that locates the position of a mobile phone using GPS.

We are developing a port management website and we need that module to keep track of people getting in and out of a particular area. we just need to integrate the mobile phone's GPS and have it tracked on the website.

We are new to this technology so we apologize if the question is quite vague. we appreciate your answers! thank you!

Comment: please provide at least a minimalistic code example of what you tried yet ...

Comment: we haven't tried anything just yet because we don't know where to start.

Comment: You'll need assistance from software on the phone if you want its GPS data, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking). Also note that this tracking scheme is trivial to circumvent.

Comment: we do not actually want this as a part of our website but our instructors demand it. so we don't have any choice.

Answer (score 1):

We are developing this kind of applications for long and what I feel from your question is that you are trying to simply track the mobile phone! If it's an iOS, you can make an app and install it to send the GPS data to an web service (preferably RESTful) and again fetch the data on the web site from that same service to track the phone in real time. Most of the companies use this approach to track anything (Car, Person etc.) that carries a cell phone.

Explaining your end goal or sharing a bit more of your target may yield better replies.

Comment: we do not actually want to track the phone sir, we just need to verify if the person using the phone is within a particular area, but we'll try to do just that sir. thank you for your answer.

Comment: Calculating within the area will also need to get the person's current lat/long, after that you can calculate if he is within the desired area. the approach varies a lot depending the end goal, I just tried to give you a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

create one android/IOS app that constantly updates it's co-ordinates (lang-lat) to database present on the webserver .
you will need following things 
1)mobile app Android/IOS , it will send mobiles location using GPS to webservice 
2)webservice that receives position from mobile apps and updates position of mobile in database.
3)website that will fetch data from that database and perform operation eg.suppose if user in certain area 
  if (location==chicago city) ##check the lang-lats for location from database
{ do this  }

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to create an app.....
You could create a webpage and get the location of a device by using [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) and send the location to server/webservice. However, this means that you need open the page with a browser to get it working.

As for keeping track of people getting in and out of a particular area, you could get the GPS co-ordinates of the two corners of the area, and well, after that, do the math to calculate if its within the bounds or outside.

Comment: sir, can i ask how to pass the variables of the coordinates in the given code to the variables in php?

Comment: @TeamBangzch I dont know php. I'd used Javascript & ASP.NET. So basically how I did it was, Create a simple ASP.NET project with one web form & Javascript-using-Geolocation getting GPS Coordinates, then through AJAX to send it to the server.